# Get reverse of an equation - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

Let's say I have this formula, for example:

```js
function getExperience(level) {
  let a = 0;
  for (let x = 1; x < level; x += 1) {
    a += Math.floor(x + (200 * (2 ** (x / 3))));
  }

  return Math.floor(a / 4);
}


for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  console.log(`Level ${i}: ${getExperience(i)}`);
}
```

To get the experience needed for level 50, you'd do: `getExperience(50)`.

But, how would you reverse that and get the LEVEL needed for experience? So, `getLevel(20010272)` would output `50`.

Comment: You can test getExperience in a loop until you get the same result (level).

Comment: It seems there's a typo. `getExperience(50)` is `20012272`, not `20010272`. So I guess `getLevel(20010272)` should return `49`, not `50`.

Comment: This is an infinite series, but you could simplify and get an inverse function.

Comment: See also [How can I calculate current level from total XP, when each level requires proportionally more XP?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110431/how-can-i-calculate-current-level-from-total-xp-when-each-level-requires-propor) on [gamedev.se].

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Short answer

You can use `4.328085 * Math.log(0.00519842 * xp + 1.259921045)` as a very good approximation of the corresponding level.

If you need an exact value, you could iterate over all levels until you find the desired range, as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434757/get-reverse-of-an-equation-javascript/54434851#54434851).

## Long answer

### Slightly modified function

I don't think it's possible to find an exact, [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for the inverse of this function. It should be possible if you modify `getExperience(level)` a bit, though.

- First, you can notice that `x` grows *much* slower than `2 ** (x / 3)`.
- Then, `Math.floor` doesn't have much influence over large numbers.

So let's remove them! Here's the slightly modified function:

```
function getExperienceEstimate(level) {
  let a = 0;
  for (let x = 1; x < level; x += 1) {
    a += 200 * (2 ** (x / 3));
  }
  return a / 4;
}
```

The advantage of this method is that it's now a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula), so it's possible to calculate the sum [directly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(200%20*%202%20**%20(i%20%2F%203),%20i,%201,%20n-1)%20%2F%204), without any loop:

```
function getExperienceEstimate(level) {
  let a = 50;
  let r = 2 ** (1 / 3);
  return a * (r**level - r) / (r - 1);
};
```

`getExperienceEstimate(50)` returns `20011971.993575357`, which is only 0.0015% smaller than `getExperience(50)`.

### Inverse function

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve((50%20(2%5E(n%2F3)%20-%202%5E(1%2F3)))%2F(2%5E(1%2F3)%20-%201)%3D%20xp,%20n)), here's the inverse function of `getExperienceEstimate`:

```
function getLevelEstimate(xp){
  let a = 50;
  let r = 2 ** (1 / 3);
  return Math.log(xp * (r - 1) / a + r) / Math.log(r);
};
```

With some minor precision loss, you can simplify it further:

```
function getLevelEstimate(xp){
  return 4.328085 * Math.log(0.00519842 * xp + 1.259921045)
};
```

It's only an estimate, but it works pretty well and doesn't require any loop!

### Test

For 20012272 XP, the approximate inverse function returns `50.00006263463371`, which should be a good starting point if you want to find the exact result.

```js
function getExperience(level) {
  let a = 0;
  for (let x = 1; x < level; x += 1) {
    a += Math.floor(x + (200 * (2 ** (x / 3))));
  }
  return Math.floor(a / 4);
}

function getLevelEstimate(xp){
  return 4.328085 * Math.log(0.00519842 * xp + 1.259921045)
};

for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  console.log(`Level ${i} (XP = ${getExperience(i)}). Estimated level : ${getLevelEstimate(getExperience(i))}`);
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I would go for. In my game, I made sure I could directly inverse my level formula by using the same exponent to both log and pow. I would recommend OP do that if at all possible to minimize the worry about approximation and instead to make it an exact match.

Comment: You could start with this approximation, then loop over a few nearby numbers to find the right one.

Comment: And from your results, it looks like simply doing `Math.round(getLevelEstimate(experience))` would work.

Comment: I also tried to find the inverse of the experience formula but failed. +1.

Comment: @Barmar: The interesting information is for which experience `getLevelEstimate` switches to the next level. If you call `Math.round`, you throw away this information. With a perfect `getLevelEstimate`, `Math.floor` should return the correct level.

Comment: I come back and see this. You're too kind. Thank you.

Comment: @GreenMtn: My pleasure, I always enjoy short mathematical challenges. And I received a hard-to-get badge with this answer, so thank you too ;) Finally : Note that you don't have to accept my answer, since it only delivers an approximate result.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to avoid to loop over all possibilities.

[Here](https://hackernoon.com/programming-with-js-binary-search-aaf86cef9cb3) is an example that I have adapted to your case.

You first need to create an array to map all your `level => experience`, this action should be done only ONCE, then you never have to do it again.

As you can see in my example, even with 1000 levels, you never have to iterate more than 9 times whatever level you are trying to find.

```js
// You first have to create an array with all your levels.
// This has to be done only ONCE because it's an expensive one!
const list = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
  list[i] = getExperience(i);
}

function getExperience(level) {
  let a = 0;
  for (let x = 1; x < level; x += 1) {
    a += Math.floor(x + (200 * (2 ** (x / 3))));
  }

  return Math.floor(a / 4);
}

function getLevel(value) {
  // initial values for start, middle and end
  let start = 0
  let stop = list.length - 1
  let middle = Math.floor((start + stop) / 2)
  let iterations = 0;
  
  // While the middle is not what we're looking for and the list does not have a single item.
  while (list[middle] !== value && start < stop) {
    iterations++;
    if (value < list[middle]) {
      stop = middle - 1
    } else {
      start = middle + 1
    }

    // Recalculate middle on every iteration.
    middle = Math.floor((start + stop) / 2)
  }
  
  console.log(`${value} is Level ${middle} (Result found after ${iterations} iterations)`);
  return middle;
}

// Then you can search your level according to the experience
getLevel(0);
getLevel(72);
getLevel(20010272);
getLevel(getExperience(50));
getLevel(33578608987644589722);
```

Comment: You can improve creation of the list by looping `Math.floor(x + (200 * (2 ** (x / 3))))` from 1 to 1000 and storing the `a` values, then looping again to get `Math.floor(a / 4)`

Comment: @JollyJoker Hmm possible, can you edit my answer with your suggestion?

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@xDoIwFEVn/Yo7tggF1IUBE@PsF5AODVRFgTYtkJLw79huLr7hvZzh5OS9xSxsbVo9JoNq5LbVarAjnEaJijF2NUYspCgKyj5ysYTy/Y71QhOH8gJ3yOkv38X4Yo9OKeP5AHLMMkT@IPLbIcWJhvGKkc1US0JEDBejpcEOvcDBFFWb5BzriozyGBWnSFPcpn7qxNjOEnbq/5ZTnH0kfKI6yTr1JE7TbfsC "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Edit it in if you want to; it's not as readable as I'd like

Comment: @EricDuminil Absolutely, it was an `index` problem with the initialization of the list, I fixed it, thank you.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY@7bsMwDEX3fAVHMrFVOe2aAl06tVNHwwPhqKlb2TLoBxQg/@7SCZyHBhEEcQ/O/eWRu1Kqtk@bsHfTVIam60G4OTjYQYTdK@TGmDcRPmJMMzJ/7tghFabmFs/3uMlotboEY/se5MONzmvaz9dP7n/Mtw9B0MMGcGstrHXAWn8PT/BM@pZ8OdSD574a3ddQK4JFZogOI24/lA6RE4gJVLSozfsM5rxKswJOJ7BUJJAXd1JKeiDjuSBm1lq6FLl6E92a3blHNX1ZPIN3xoeDpmia/gE "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") Split to named functions, maybe a bit more readable

Comment: You **dont** have to build the list of all experiences.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, it depends on how you use it in your app. At least Green Mtn has several solutions and can choose the best one for his case.

Answer (score 11):

A brute-force (but inelegant) solution would be to just call `getExperience` for levels until you reach a level that requires more experience than the passed `exp`:

```js
function getLevel(exp) {
  if (exp === 0) return 0;
  let level = 0;
  let calcExp = 0;
  while (exp > calcExp) {
    calcExp = getExperience(level);
    if (calcExp > exp) break;
    level++;
  }
  return level - 1;
}

console.log(getLevel(20012272)); // experience required for 50 on the dot
console.log(getLevel(20012270));
console.log(getLevel(20012274));
console.log(getLevel(0));

function getExperience(level) {
  let a = 0;
  for (let x = 1; x < level; x += 1) {
    a += Math.floor(x + (200 * (2 ** (x / 3))));
  }

  return Math.floor(a / 4);
}
```

Comment: Just wondering if we can minimize the iteration by setting `level` to a relatively nearer value

Comment: A simple solution that gets the job done. Why did I think of this. Argh. Thank you.

Comment: You could, of course, pre-compute all the values and have them in a lookup table. I doubt the XP requirement or levels would change all the time, so dynamically computing them every single time seems like an overkill.

Comment: If you knew minimum/maximum levels as well, you could do a pseudo-binary search (i.e. if you knew there are exactly 100 levels, you see if your experience is less than or greater than level 50's, then 25/75 depending on that, then 12/38/62/88, etc). Or somewhere between those steps (bisect until you have 3 options, then check all those).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [binary search](https://hackernoon.com/programming-with-js-binary-search-aaf86cef9cb3) to locate level value faster - in 7 steps max.

(while I doubt that gain is significant for length 100 list)